# Custom formula for google sheets that highlights cells in a row that are less than a specific value in the row

Tags: google-sheets-formula

So I have 50 rows of data that each run January to December sales data and then a column that is the average for the row. I want to do conditional formatting to color cells that are less than the average but I do not want to do this 50 times each with a different range. Is there a formula that would work?

I can do it for one row but I cannot scale it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the following set-up:

1. January to December are Columns A through to L.
2. Average Column is M.

Highlight the cells for the conditional formatting, which would be the range:
`=A2:M50`

Use the custom formula: `=A2<$M2`

The **$** means each column will always be compared to the average column.
This will then work for every row in that range.

---

Alternatively, the formula `=B2<AVERAGE($B2:$M2)` will achieve the same result but calculate the average itself.